# Multiple AJAX calls with delay in server

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm getting crazy with an issue with Ajax calls and my apache server.

I've some scripts php and one simple html with javascript.

```
var i = 0;
var t = 0;
function comenzar(){
    $.get('testAjax2.php', function (data){
        $('#container').append(data);
    });
    t = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#container').append('timeout<br/>');
        i++;
        $.get('testAjax.php?i='+i, function (data){
        $('#container').append(data);
        });
        if(i == 10)
            clearTimeout(t);
    }, 100);
}
```

PHP file testAjax2.php code:

```
sleep(10); //sleeps for 10 seconds
echo "done! testAjax2.php";
```

PHP file testAjax.php code:

```
echo $_GET['i']."<br/>";
```

People What do you think about this code?

I can not make any ajax calls until It has completed the first one. It shows Number one only when testAjax2 ajax call has finished.

How can I do a multiple ajax call when the first one has server delay and keep making calls?

I'm totally lost, I didn't know this behavior about Ajax (or maybe Jquery?)

Thank you so much

EDIT: Sorry for my english

Comment: Wat do you meant? Do you need to execute 2nd AJAX call only after 1st AJAX Call finishes?

Comment: Your code really doesn't make any sense and your writing either. Please try to rewrite at least the English text.

Comment: That's right! I meant that!

Comment: Then call next ajax request in success callback of previous, and not by setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a simple example for your requirement. I simply added a success callback, which means the function assigned to success callback will be called once after the 1st AJAX call succeeded. In the call back function you add a next AJAX Call.

```
$.ajax('testAjax2.php', 
        success: callNextFunction,            
});

function callNextFunction(data)
{
    $('#container').append(data);

    $.get('testAjax.php?i='+i, function (data){

        $('#container').append(data);

    });
}
```

Comment: That is not what I want... The meaning of doing this is to know How is going the first ajax call with timeout function (and show some info text about first testAjax2.php). What if first ajax call lasts 10 minutes (doing things with my database)? I just want to know how much seconds left to finish test2ajax function (making periodic calls with timeout). Sorry for my english!

Comment: @MrViSiOn If you make an ajax call wait 10 minutes for a response, that means you're consuming an HTTPD thread for an entire 10 minutes. Being that most browsers only allow for 2 concurrent HTTPD threads, I'd probably be inclined not to visit your site.

Comment: @MrViSiOn, Why do you really need to make a call wait for 10 mins. Can you explain your requirements ?

Comment: 1. Calls which long 10 min will end in a timeout. No browser waits 10 minute for a response.
2. What should the timeout do for you what a callback function can't do? Show a spinner or something bevor you launch your ajax request and hide it again when you got the response from the server.

Comment: Ok, Ill try to explain myself. testAjax2.php makes a lot of cURL request (a hundred) and write HTMl answer in a database, I just want to know with second ajax call how much rows that table has for showing 0/100, 1/100, 2/100, 3/100 and so on in a web page. clear? Thanks for everything...

Comment: That's not possible the way you're doing it. You'd need to make the operation identificable and write the status information to a file or a database. With a second endpoint you could read this information and in your interval. Without a second PHP script and some kind of DB it's impossible to work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem is with ajax behavior. Because ajax is asynchronous, so it is not waiting for response and will execute the next ajax request so if you have any statement which is dependent on the complition or response value of the first ajax request than you should put that code in success event of ajax method.

Comment: Try this code, please. Try it and you will see that you don't see 1,2,3,4,5... while first ajax call isn't finished...

Comment: Ok, Ill try to explain myself. testAjax2.php makes a lot of cURL request (a hundred) and write HTMl answer in a database, I just want to know with second ajax call how much rows that table has for showing 0/100, 1/100, 2/100, 3/100 and so on in a web page. clear? Thanks for everything...